# Interesting Quirk when painting images in Java

Tags: java, paintcomponent

It seems that this method:

```
public abstract boolean drawImage(Image img,
            int x,
            int y,
            ImageObserver observer)
```

And the other overloaded methods will not draw the image until I resize the frame. However all other methods for painting geometric primitives display the correct shape as soon as the frame is first opened. What this means is that if I want to have the frame open in the center of the screen, being exactly as big as the image I'm drawing, then I need to resize the frame, to make it take up the entire screen, then resize it to the smaller size. Because of this behavior I must have setResizeable(true) enabled.
Why are the drawImage methods different?
And how can I display the image properly, without the need to resize the frame?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

EDIT: Some people wanted to see my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawingSpace());
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class DrawingSpace extends JComponent {
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    URL imageURL = null;
    try {
        imageURL = new URL("http://a.tgcdn.net/images/products/zoom/rubix_cube.jpg");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imageURL);
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();
}
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code where you call drawImage?

Comment: @TomJonckheere I added the code

Comment: Anyone care to help me?

Comment: @TomJonckheere I posted the code and you did not respond, I wonder if you just forgot.

Comment: Avi, I Looked at your code, when I run it the Image isn't loaded... I havent forget it, I just don't have the time right now to study it in depth...

Comment: @TomJonckheere Try resizing the window.